# Como puedo ver mi proyecto laravel en una red local

Tags: laravel, redes, networking

alguien sabe como puedo ver mi proyecto en laravel mediante otro dispositivo en la misma red local?

Ingrese mi ip en el navegador y me abre la configuración de wamp y cuando ingreso el nombre de mi carpeta me abre la principal pero las demás paginas no

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una forma sencilla de hacerlo sin configurar nada es usando esta variación en tu comando `php artisan serve` por `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000`

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que crear o redireccionar el vhost de apache a la carpeta que quieras en lugar de a htdocs

Ejemplo

Abre

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache-XXX\conf\extra\ (XXX = version)
```

Y editas tu vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:\nuevaRuta"
    ServerName mipagina.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Ahora solo reinicia el wamp y listo

Comment: deberias poner un ejemplo en el cual pongas un ejemplo

Comment: Ya puse un ejemplo rapido

Comment: Ya te quite el negativo